# Window & Aggregate functions in Pyspark SQL/SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

After the answer by @Vaebhav realized the question was not set up correctly.
Hence editing it with his code snippet.

I have the following table

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,TimestampType,DoubleType

input_str = """
4219,2018-01-01 08:10:00,3.0,50.78,
4216,2018-01-02 08:01:00,5.0,100.84,
4217,2018-01-02 20:00:00,4.0,800.49,
4139,2018-01-03 11:05:00,1.0,400.0,
4170,2018-01-03 09:10:00,2.0,100.0,
4029,2018-01-06 09:06:00,6.0,300.55,
4029,2018-01-06 09:16:00,2.0,310.55,
4217,2018-01-06 09:36:00,5.0,307.55,
1139,2018-01-21 11:05:00,1.0,400.0,
2170,2018-01-21 09:10:00,2.0,100.0,
4218,2018-02-06 09:36:00,5.0,307.55,
4218,2018-02-06 09:36:00,5.0,307.55
""".split(",")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, input_str))
cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "customer_id,timestamp,quantity,price".split(',')))
n = len(input_values)
n_cols = 4
input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_cols]) for i in range(0,n,n_cols)]
sparkDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(input_list,cols)
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('customer_id',F.col('customer_id').cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('timestamp',F.col('timestamp').cast(TimestampType()))\
                 .withColumn('quantity',F.col('quantity').cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('price',F.col('price').cast(DoubleType()))
```

I want to calculate the aggergate as follows :

| trxn_date | unique_cust_visits | next_7_day_visits | next_30_day_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 7 | 9 |
| 2018-01-02 | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 2018-01-03 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2018-01-21 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-02-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

where the

- trxn_date is date from the timestamp column,
- daily_cust_visits is unique count of customers,
- next_7_day_visits is a count of customers on a 7 day rolling window basis.
- next_30_day_visits is a count of customers on a 30 day rolling window basis.

I want to write the code as a single SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `ROW` rather than a `RANGE` Frame Type , a good explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/kzhang28/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-sql-windows.adoc)

> **ROW** - based on physical offsets from the position of the current input row
>
> **RANGE** - based on logical offsets from the position of the current input row

Also in your implementation ,a `PARTITION BY` clause would be redundant, as it wont create the required `Frames` for a look-ahead.

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
4219,2018-01-02 08:10:00,3.0,50.78,
4216,2018-01-02 08:01:00,5.0,100.84,
4217,2018-01-02 20:00:00,4.0,800.49,
4139,2018-01-03 11:05:00,1.0,400.0,
4170,2018-01-03 09:10:00,2.0,100.0,
4029,2018-01-06 09:06:00,6.0,300.55,
4029,2018-01-06 09:16:00,2.0,310.55,
4217,2018-01-06 09:36:00,5.0,307.55
""".split(",")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "customer_id  timestamp   quantity    price".split('\t')))
        
n = len(input_values)
n_cols = 4

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_cols]) for i in range(0,n,n_cols)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,cols)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('customer_id',F.col('customer_id').cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('timestamp',F.col('timestamp').cast(TimestampType()))\
                 .withColumn('quantity',F.col('quantity').cast(IntegerType()))\
                 .withColumn('price',F.col('price').cast(DoubleType()))

sparkDF.show()

+-----------+-------------------+--------+------+
|customer_id|          timestamp|quantity| price|
+-----------+-------------------+--------+------+
|       4219|2018-01-02 08:10:00|       3| 50.78|
|       4216|2018-01-02 08:01:00|       5|100.84|
|       4217|2018-01-02 20:00:00|       4|800.49|
|       4139|2018-01-03 11:05:00|       1| 400.0|
|       4170|2018-01-03 09:10:00|       2| 100.0|
|       4029|2018-01-06 09:06:00|       6|300.55|
|       4029|2018-01-06 09:16:00|       2|310.55|
|       4217|2018-01-06 09:36:00|       5|307.55|
+-----------+-------------------+--------+------+
```

#### Window Aggregates

```
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("transactions")

sql.sql("""
        SELECT 
            TO_DATE(timestamp) as trxn_date
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as unique_cust_visits
            ,SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)) OVER (
                        ORDER BY 'timestamp'
                        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 7 FOLLOWING
            ) as next_7_day_visits
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY 1
""").show()

+----------+------------------+-----------------+
| trxn_date|unique_cust_visits|next_7_day_visits|
+----------+------------------+-----------------+
|2018-01-02|                 3|                7|
|2018-01-03|                 2|                4|
|2018-01-06|                 2|                2|
+----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: ROW range will result in aggregating of continous rows, however since I am dealing with transaction data, RANGE suits better.
I have edited my question to provide a better example.
However, your answer did guide me towards the right solution :)

Comment: I see what you did your answer , glad its working now , do upvote and accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Vaebhav's answer the required query in this case is

```
sqlContext.sql("""
        SELECT 
            TO_DATE(timestamp) as trxn_date
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as unique_cust_visits
            ,SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)) OVER (
                        ORDER BY CAST(TO_DATE(timestamp) AS TIMESTAMP) DESC
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) as next_7_day_visits
            ,SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)) OVER (
                        ORDER BY CAST(TO_DATE(timestamp) AS TIMESTAMP) DESC
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 30 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) as next_30_day_visits
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER by trxn_date
""").show()
```

| trxn_date | unique_cust_visits | next_7_day_visits | next_30_day_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 7 | 9 |
| 2018-01-02 | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 2018-01-03 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2018-01-21 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-02-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 |